# Strong law of large numbers for square-integrable and uncorrelated random variables with bounded variance

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and  $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of square-integrable and uncorrelated (maybe we actually need independence) random variables $\Omega\to [0,\infty]$ with $V:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Var}X_n<\infty$.

Moreover, let $$X^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\overline{X}^{(n)}:=\frac{1}{n}X^{(n)}$$

I want to show, that it holds: $$\limsup_{i\to\infty}\left|\overline{X}^{(i)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(i)}\right]\right|=0\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag{1}$$

*Proof*: Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $$k_n:=\lfloor(1+\varepsilon)^n\rfloor\ge\frac{1}{2}(1+\varepsilon)^n\tag{2}$$

[Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) yields
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Pr\left[\left|\overline{X}^{(k_n)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\right]\right|\ge\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^{n/4}}\right]&\le&\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(1+\varepsilon)^{n/2}\operatorname{Var}\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{\le}&\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(1+\varepsilon)^{n/2}\frac{V}{k_n}\\&\stackrel{\text{(2)}}{\le}&2V\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^{n/2}}&<\infty
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $(*)$ holds by uncorrelatedness and the [formula of Bienaymé](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29).

Thus, the [lemma of Borel-Cantelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) yields $$\Pr\left[\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left|\overline{X}^{(k_n)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\right]\right|\ge\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^{n/4}}\right\}\right]=0,$$ i.e. there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $m\ge n$ $$\left|\overline{X}^{(k_n)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\right]\right|<\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^{n/4}}\;\;\;\text{almost surely}$$ So, we've got $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\overline{X}^{(k_n)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\right]\right|=0\;\;\;\text{alsmost surely}\tag{3}$$ Now, observe that $$k_{n+1}\le(1+2\varepsilon)k_n$$ which implies that 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{1+2\varepsilon}\overline{X}^{(k_n)}&\le& \frac{k_n}{k_{n+1}}\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{k_{n+1}}X^{(k_n)}\\&\le& \overline{X}^{(i)}\\&\le&\frac{1}{k_n}X^{(k_{n+1})}\\&\le &(1+2\varepsilon)\overline{X}^{(k_{n+1})}
\end{split}\tag{4}
\end{equation}
for all $i\in [k_n,k_{n+1}]\cap\mathbb{N}$.

**How can we conclude, that** $$L:=\limsup_{i\to\infty}\left|\overline{X}^{(i)}-E\left[\overline{X}^{(i)}\right]\right|=0\tag{5}$$ **almost surely?**

<sub>My first idea was to use $(4)$ to see that $$L\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|(1+2\varepsilon)\overline{X}^{(k_{n+1})}-E\left[\frac{1}{1+2\varepsilon}\overline{X}^{(k_n)}\right]\right|\tag{6}$$However, I am not able to take advantage of $(3)$ in $(6)$.</sub>

Comment: Do the $X_k$ have the same distribution?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo No, not necessarily.

Comment: How do you deduce (2) from the assumptions?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I've completely updated my question. $(2)$ is now called $(4)$ and it's derivation is explained in detail.

Comment: Your equations in your _first_ equation (4) do not hold unless the variables $X_n$ are non-negative.

Comment: Are you sure this is a true theorem?  In the standard independence case, you usually break general random variables $\{X_n\}$ into positive and negative parts and use the fact that independence implies $\{X_n^+\}$ are also independent. That is not true for uncorrelated.  I know that a stronger martingale property (slightly stronger than uncorrelated but weaker than independence) implies what you want in the general case when the variables have distribution with support over the whole number line.

Comment: @Michael As stated in the first sentence: "[The $X_n$ are] random variables $\Omega\to [0,\infty]$". So, they're non-negative.

Comment: @Michael So, I think uncorrelatedness is all we need, but I could live with independence as a stronger requirement, too. Actually, I restricted this to non-negative random variables and dropped an independence requirement, because I think we only need independence to break general random variables in the way you've described.

Comment: Okay, then you are basically done if you add a "uniformly bounded mean" assumption (see answer below).

Comment: @Michael The statement is definitively true for all square-integrable and pairwise uncorrelated random variables $\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ with bounded variance. The proof is somehow more complicated and uses a different approach. The proof idea in the question text basically shows all the steps one would make to prove the statement for square-integrable and identically distributed random variables. However, I've observed that (given bounded variance) one does not need identically distribution except for the last step.

Comment: @Michael So, I hoped one could use this idea with the given requirements too and does not need to switch to a completely different approach.

Comment: It does not make sense to allow $X_n$ to take the value $\infty$ with positive probability, since then $E[X_n]=\infty$ and the variance condition could not be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also include "uniformly bounded means," so that $E[X_n] \leq C$ for all $n$ (for some constant $C$) then you are okay. Take your *last* equation (4) (which is really equation (6)) and add and subtract the same thing to get terms $E[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}](1+2\epsilon) - E[\overline{X}^{(k_n)}](1+2\epsilon)$ to finish (via triangle inequality).

---

I would also phrase your conclusion before (3) differently: "Almost surely, there exists an $n$ such that $|\overline{X}^{k_m}-E[\overline{X}^{k_m}]| < 1/(1+\epsilon)^{m/4}$ for all $m \geq n$.

---

It seemed to me that taking away the "uniformly bounded means" assumption was very similar  to taking away the "non-negative" assumption, and so one should imply the other. Thus, at first I thought non-negativity (and hence "uniformly bounded mean") was crucial.  However, after playing around, I believe the following is a proof for the general "non-negative" case, which also does not require uniformly bounded means.  The proof uses existence of a sequence of non-decreasing positive integers $k_n$ that satisfy:

1) $k_1 = 1$.

2) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} k_n = \infty$

3) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/k_n < \infty$

4) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k_{n+1}}{k_n}-1\right)^2 < \infty$.

Using $k_n = \left\lfloor \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n^{0.6}}\right)^n\right\rfloor$ will do, since $k_n \approx e^{(1/2)n^{0.4}}$ and so increases super-linearly, but $(k_{n+1}/k_n-1)^2 \approx \frac{1}{4n^{1.2}}$.

Claim:  If $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are uncorrelated and $Var(X_n) \leq V$ for all $n$ (for some finite constant $V$), then (with prob 1): 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_n-E[X_n]) = 0 $$

Proof: Let $k_n$ be a non-decreasing sequence of positive integers with the above four properties.  Fix $\epsilon>0$.  By Chebyshev:

$$ Pr\left[\left|\frac{1}{k_n}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} (X_i-E[X_i])\right| \geq \epsilon  \right] 
\leq \frac{k_n V}{\epsilon^2 k_n^2}
= \frac{V}{\epsilon^2 k_n} $$
Thus, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/k_n < \infty$, we have: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Pr\left[\left|\frac{1}{k_n}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} (X_i-E[X_i])\right| \geq \epsilon  \right] < \infty $$
and so (with prob 1): 
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{1}{k_n}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} (X_i-E[X_i])\right| \leq \epsilon $$ 
This holds for all $\epsilon>0$, and so (with prob 1): 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{k_n}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} (X_i-E[X_i]) = 0 \: \: \: (*) $$

Now fix $m \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and define $n_m$ as the smallest index such that $k_{n_m} \leq m \leq k_{n_m+1}$.  Then: 
\begin{align} 
&\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (X_i-E[X_i])\\
&=\frac{k_{n_m+1}}{m}\frac{1}{k_{n_m+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{k_{n_m+1}} (X_i-E[X_i])  - \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=m+1}^{k_{n_m+1}} (X_i-E[X_i])
\end{align}

If we can show both terms on the right-hand-side go to 0 as $m\rightarrow \infty$, we are done.  Taking a limit as $m\rightarrow \infty$ of the first term on the right-hand-side gives 0 (with prob 1) by equation (*). It suffices to prove that (with prob 1):

$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=m+1}^{k_{n_m+1}}(X_i-E[X_i])=0 $$

To this end, fix $\delta>0$. We have by Chebyshev: 
\begin{align} 
&Pr\left[\left|\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=m+1}^{k_{n_m+1}}(X_i-E[X_i])\right| \geq \delta\right] \\
& \leq \frac{V(k_{n_m+1}-m)}{m^2\delta^2} \\
& \leq \frac{V(k_{n_m+1}-k_{n_m})}{k_{n_m}^2 \delta^2} 
\end{align}

Summing over $m$ gives:

\begin{align} 
&\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} Pr\left[\left|\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=m+1}^{k_{n_m+1}}(X_i-E[X_i])\right| \geq \delta\right] \\
&\leq \frac{V}{\delta^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k_{n_m+1}-k_{n_m})}{k_{n_m}^2}\\
&\leq \frac{V}{\delta^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k_{n+1}-k_n)^2}{k_{n}^2} \\
&= \frac{V}{\delta^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k_{n+1}}{k_n}-1\right)^2 \\
&< \infty
\end{align} 
Thus, with prob 1:

$$ \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=m+1}^{k_{n_m+1}}(X_i-E[X_i])\right| \leq \delta $$

This holds for all $\delta$, and so the $\limsup$ must be 0 (with prob 1).

Comment: The statement is definitively true for all square-integrable and piecewise uncorrelated random variables $\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Please notice my comment below the question.

Comment: The proof for uniformly bounded means is easier and follows by one or two more steps of your last equation.  However, now I agree that uniformly bounded means is not crucial and, in fact, neither is non-negativity.  See my edits above.

Comment: That's "the more complicated approach" I mentioned earlier. Basically one can show the statement in three steps:$$$$
(1) $\overline{X}^{(n^2)}\stackrel{\text{almost surely}}{\to}0$ $$$$
(2) $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_m}{n(m)^2}\stackrel{\text{almost surely}}{\to}0$ where $n=n(m)$ is chosen such that $n^2\le m<(n+1)^2$ $$$$
(3) Conclude that $\overline{X}^{(m)}=a_m\frac{X^{(m)}}{n(m)^2}\stackrel{\text{almost surely}}{\to}0$ where $a_m=n(m)^2/m$.

Comment: In (3) one can use the following fact: For any $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and every measurable functions $f,f_n:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}(E)$ (where $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $(E,d)$ is a separable metric space) with $f_n\stackrel{\text{almost everywhere}}{\to}f$, we've got $$a_nf_n\stackrel{\text{almost everywhere}}{\to}af$$

Comment: So, what is it you are looking for?  You have not acknowledged any of my points (or even fixed the typo/mistake I pointed out in your writeup).  It seems you are not really asking a question and/or are not open to answers...?

Comment: For example, it seems you have not even tried using the triangle inequality $|a-b|\leq |a-c|+|c-b|$ in your last equation (4) (really equation (6)). I think that gives all the intuition needed, and gives insight on why you need to keep terms $X_n-E[X_n]$ together, rather than separate $X_n$ and $E[X_n]$, if you want to avoid uniformly bounded means.

Comment: I notice that $k_n = n^2$ also satisfies my four properties.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I will accept your answer, cause it seems like I didn't make clear that I was not looking for a proof of the statement from scratch. Instead, I hoped one could use the already shown steps to prove it. I don't understand what you mean by "keep $X_n-E[X_n]$" together. I didn't separate them in $(6)$. Moreover, I don't see how the triangle inequality helps in $(6)$.

Comment: I see the use of $k_n$ and $k_{n+1}$ makes it harder than I expected, but you can use a sum of 3 terms: $|(1+2\epsilon)\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{1+2\epsilon}E[\overline{X}^{k_n}]| \leq |(1+2\epsilon)\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}}-(1+2\epsilon)E[\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}}]|+|(1+2\epsilon)E[\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}}] - \frac{1}{1+2\epsilon}E[\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}}]| + \frac{1}{1+2\epsilon}|E[\overline{X}^{k_{n+1}}] - E[\overline{X}^{k_n}]|$

Comment: The first term goes to 0, the second is $O(\epsilon)$ which disappears when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ (assuming we have a bounded mean), and the third I think can also be bounded in terms of $\epsilon$ (assuming a bounded mean).

Comment: Your equation before (3) needs to use "$m$" somewhere. Also, there is a difference between "there exists $n_0$ such that $Pr\left[\cap_{n\geq n_0} A_n\right]=1$." and "$Pr\left[\cup_{n_0=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n\geq n_0}A_n\right]=1$." The latter is what we need but the wording before (3) seems to suggest the former.

Comment: So the $|a-b|\leq |a-c|+|c-d|+|d-b|$ approach completes your argument, but it requires uniformly bounded means.  The only way to remove the “uniformly bounded means” assumption is to define $Z_n = X_n-E[X_n]$ and then produce a proof that _only uses the $Z_n$ variables_.  This is  the intuition that led me to my proof in the answer above. Of course, any such proof can no longer use non-negativity, since the $Z_n$ variables are not non-negative.

Comment: The conclusion is:  _Doing it your way is impossible unless you also assume uniformly bounded means._